# Create relation between an entity and non-entity objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, many-to-many

I have some domain object in my webapp named of Site.
Site would be contains list of IP addresses, that is

```
@Entity
class Site {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<String> ips= new HashSet<String>();

    ...

}
```

But hibernate is down when I try to start webapp with error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: my.webapp.Site.ips[java.lang.String]
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use relational annotations (i.e. `@ManyToMany`) if you don't have a relationship with an Entity. If you have basic type (as in this case - String) you should use [`@ElementCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)